# Editor width automatically reduced - text is wrapped after 1 character

Tags: editor, block-editor

I have created several blocks using the wordpress editor.  When I first create them, everything looks fine.  When I revisit the editing page after some time, the  width of the text block has shrunk down to 1 character, and is wrapping text making it a huge pain to do any editing. The actual page is unchanged. This is just the editing window

This is the second time this has happened, the first time I deleted everything and re-created the blocks. When the page first loads, the editor looks good but then the page updates and everything squeezes down to just a few characters wide.

Is there a way to fix this that doesn't require editing the CSS code?

I'm using a 1&1 IONOS managed wordpress site.  I'm new to WP so I'm not sure what other information I can provide.

[image]

Comment: Hello. This is not a support website and you should only ask questions regarding development (code). If you're using a custom block / theme, ask the seller to help you.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  Didn't realize.